# Are $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ flat modules?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I have the following three question about flat modules.

1. Why is not $\mathbb{Z}$ a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
2. Why is $\mathbb{Q}$ a flat module $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
3. I need an example of a module which is not flat, nor injective, nor projective.

Thanks a lot!

**Note:**  I need only a hint to attack those problems not the complete answer.

Comment: As modules over what?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks. I edit it.

Comment: Wait, $\Bbb Z$ is not a flat $\Bbb Z$-module?

Comment: @QuangHoang projective modules are flat.

Comment: Then the last point is not posible.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: Exactly, I was wondering about OP's first question.

Comment: @YotasTrejos yes it is. My remark only eliminates the possibility of a module which isn't flat, but is projective.

Comment: @QuangHoang Oh, sorry, I misread the question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. $\Bbb Z$ is a free, hence projective, hence flat $\Bbb Z$ module.
2. $\Bbb Z$ modules are flat iff they are torsion-free, and $\Bbb Q_\Bbb Z$ is torsion-free. (And this is another reason $\Bbb Z_\Bbb Z$ is flat.)
3. $\Bbb Z$ modules are injective iff they are divisible, so to produce a nonflat, noninjective module, it suffices to think of a nontorsion-free module and a nondivisible module and take their product. So, for example, $\Bbb Z/(n)\oplus\Bbb Z.$

Comment: 3. Why not $\mathbb{Z}/n$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Because that doesn't illustrate the general principle for making simultaneous counterexamples for two conditions stable under direct sums that I wanted to apply. Being able to come up with a single module that lacks both properties is good, but sometimes difficult, so this is a strategy worth knowing.